# Hbase remote shell command

Tags: regex, linux, shell, hbase

I want to create a hbase shell in the remote server as below

```
[root@localhost ~]#` ssh root@<hostname> " echo 'create '\'"sample'\'"','\'"cf'\'"' | hbase shell -n "`

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will
likely be removed in a future release
19/06/28 07:25:55 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated.
Instead, use io.native.lib.available
ERROR SyntaxError: stdin:1: syntax error, unexpected null

create 'sample',\cf'
                ^
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Have fixed the above issue with EOF option like below

```
    ssh root@<hostname> <<-EOF
    echo " create 'table',schema "| hbase shell -n
```

EOF